# Unbalanced Column Width: Last two columns too wide

Tags: tables, captions, siunitx

I have the following code. When I compile it, the last two column is too wide. I have tried \makebox and set column width, but neither of those works. Could it be the multicolumn that I used? Below is what I have got now. I am hoping to set columns with equal width and fit the page. Could you please help me fix this issue? Thanks so much!

[image: B]

```
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S[table-format=5.4,table-number-alignment=center]}}
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{TABLE 3}} \\
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Results of Regressions of CAR on Earnings Surprise Scaled by Price (ES) by Dispersion of Analyst Forecasts (DS) Grouping (ES = 0 observations included)}}  \\
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{$CAR=\beta\textsubscript{0}+\beta\textsubscript{1}ES+\varepsilon$}\\
        \hline\hline
         & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pred.Interval}   \\ 
        \cline{5-6}
        ±Range of & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ES \textless\space 0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ES \textgreater\space 0}  \\
        ES & \textit{n} & $\beta$\textsubscript{0} & $\beta$\textsubscript{1} & UPI\textsubscript{.667}  & LPI\textsubscript{.667}   \\ 
        \hline
        Unrestricted & 14635 & 0.0114 & 0.0000 & 0.1678 & -0.0001    \\
        .02          & 10010 & 0.0123 & 2.4056*** & 0.1371 & 0.0135  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: avoid scaling tables `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}` will produce inconsistent font sizes.  Remove your multicolumn{6}  and before the tabular use `\caption{Results of Regres...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid scaling tables `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}` will produce inconsistent font sizes.

Remove your `multicolumn{6}` and before the tabular use `\caption{Results of Regres...}`

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions, in no particular order.

- Learn how to use the `\caption` command, and how to use the `caption` package to apply high-level formatting instructions to affect the appearance of captions.
- Don't use `adjustbox` (or, for that matter, `\scalebox`) unless you really, really want to generate tables with wildly inconsistent -- and more often than not illegibly small -- font sizes.
- Please take the time to learn at least the basics of TeX's math mode and notation. Thus, do learn that `\beta\textsubscript{0}+\beta\textsubscript{1}` may be written much more succinctly as `\beta_0+\beta_1`.
- Do take the time to learn how to employ the `S` column type machinery of the `siunitx` package.
- Consider replacing `\hline` and `\cline` with macros provided the `booktabs` package: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule`

All of these ideas are implemented in the following test document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,  % for S column type
            caption,  % advanced formatting of table and figure captions
            booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % variable names in math mode

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{table}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}
\centering

%% Formatting instructions for caption:
\captionsetup{labelfont = bf,
              textfont  = it,
              labelsep  = newline,
              justification = centering}
\caption{Results of regressions of $\vn{CAR}$ on earnings surprise 
scaled by price $(\vn{ES})$ by dispersion of analyst forecasts 
$(\vn{DS})$ Grouping. $\vn{ES} = 0$ observations included.}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l
        S[table-format= 5.0,group-separator={,}]
        S[table-format= 1.4]
        S[table-format= 1.4{***}]
        S[table-format= 1.4]
        S[table-format=-1.4]
        @{}}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{$\vn{CAR} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \vn{ES} + \varepsilon$}\\
\toprule
& & & & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Pred.\ Interval}   \\ 
\cmidrule(l){5-6}
±Range of & & & & {$\vn{ES}<0$} & {$\vn{ES}>0$}  \\
ES & {$n$} & {$\beta_0$} & {$\beta_1$} & {$\vn{UPI}_{0.667}$} & {$\vn{LPI}_{0.667}$}  \\ 
\midrule
  Unrestricted & 14635 & 0.0114 & 0.0000    & 0.1678 & -0.0001  \\
  0.02         & 10010 & 0.0123 & 2.4056*** & 0.1371 &  0.0135  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```